# Why is this giving me "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable" when I converted the list to strings

Tags: python

Why is this giving me:

> "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

when I converted the list to strings:

```
def giveMeFive (start, end):
    numbers = list(range(start,end))
    for x in numbers:
        [str(x) for x in numbers]
        if str(5) in x:
            return x
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect from `str(5) in x`, given than `x` is an integer? Also, why not just write `'5'`?

Comment: "when I converted the list to strings" - no you did not

Comment: because  argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? Please provide a full problem statement so that we can help. There are several potential errors in your code, but each depends on what you are attempting to do. Please see [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code

```
def giveMeFive (start, end):
    numbers = list(range(start,end))
    return numbers.index(5)
```

Comment: Completely wrong. You should first find out what it should do. Also, use English.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `[str(x) for x in numbers]` all by itself, you are creating a new list of strings, and then immediately throwing it away. You have to save it in a variable to keep it.

Try

```
def giveMeFive (start, end):
    numbers = list(range(start,end))
    strings = [str(x) for x in numbers]
    for x in strings:
        if str(5) in x:
            return x
```

Now, there are more errors in your code, but hopefully this will get you unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear, this code is intended to return all numbers within a specific range that contain the string "5".